# Just and Weese I: Proof of Generalized Recursive Definitions

Tags: induction, set-theory, recursion

In Section 4.2 of "Discovering Modern Set Theory I." by Just and Weese, The proof of Theorem 25 (Principle of Generalized Recursive Definitions) considers the set of all $z \in Z$ such that there exists a function $F_z : I(z) \to X$ such that
$F(y) = G(F|I(y),y)$ for each $y \in I(z)$.
I am confused by this, and not just for lack of subscripts on $F$.

1) Since a wellfounded relation need not be transitive, $F_z(y) = G(F_z|I(y),y)$ does not seem to work, because $F_z|I(y)$ may not be a total function from $I(y)$ to $X$ since $y \in I(z) \kern.6em\not\kern -.6em \implies I(y) \subseteq I(z)$.

2) $F_z(y) = G(F_y|I(y),y)$ seems more plausible, but other $F_y$ have not been introduced in the preceding prose (whereas $F_z$ is explicitly quantified).

Should $F_z$'s domain be expanded to include the "downward closure" of $z$ with respect to the well-founded relation $W$, or am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds like you might be right. I don't have the resource in front of me, do you mind giving the definition of $I(y)$ please? You might want to take the transitive closure of $I(z)$ maybe?

Comment: If $W$ is a wellfounded relation, then $I(y) = \{ x \mid x W y \}$

Comment: I see. I assume that $W$ is some set like relation of a set $X$. We do need to indeed consider the transitive closure of each subset $Y$ of $X$. For each element $y\in I(z)$ the set of predecessor $I(y)$ must be a subset of $I(z)$. So basically your $F_z$ is like an approximation to the final function $F$.

Comment: Yes $W$ is set like.  Your analysis seems to coincide with mine.  Thank you!